# AFNetworking 2.0 batch requests

Tags: request, afnetworking-2

I want to create sync manager using AFNetworking 2.0. I have a separate layer where I keep all the `AFHTTPRequestOperations` and all I want to do is to enqueue them. I am able to do this using the `batchOfRequestOperations` class method of `AFURLConnectionOperation` but I am not able to cancel all the operations when one of them fails. 
In the progress block I check the status code and if for example the status is 404 i cancel all the operations in the queue. The problem is that the next operations always executes.

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer: [AFNetwork 2.0 Queue with completion block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22582860/afnetwork-2-0-queue-with-completion-block/22583040#22583040)

You can check one by one at the progress block to see if one of them cancelled, and cancel all operations in the array.